# How to read input value from the Request.Form collection by input name

Tags: asp.net, input, asp.net-4.0, request.form

I want to be able to read values of HtmlHiddenField controls from the Request.Form collection in a user control on postback. The keys in the collection seem to represent the control's name attribute rather than ID. I can control the ID using the new ClientIDMode property which helps when my user control is placed in different pages thus within different naming containers. But how can I do the same with the name attribute? The HtmlHiddenField.Name property doesn't match the key name in Reqest[key] object when in a naming control.

I understand this is quite specific scenario because I don't have access to the hidden field control object. I am just looking for a way to control how the input name attribute is rendered as is now possible for IDs.

Comment: Why don't you use plain HTML `<input type=hidden />`?

Comment: I can't change that. It's a part of my company's component.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to access the value of the hidden field using the [unique id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx) property of the control like below

```
var postedValue = Request.Forms[hdnField.UniqueId];
```