# How do you pass data between pages where the source data is in IN an asp:Content block?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've noticed that PreviousPage and Request.Form don't work if my SOURCE page has the TextBox's and such within an asp:Content block (master pages)

Is there a workaround or am I not understanding something?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" MasterPageFile="Menu.master"  %>

<asp:Content ID="pageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="pageHead" Runat="Server">
    <title>Whatever</title>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="pageContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="pageContent" Runat="Server" >
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTester" Text="YES"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat=server ID="btnTest" PostBackUrl="~/Process.aspx" />
</asp:Content>
```

Target Codebehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ltlDebug.Text = Request.Form["txtTester"];
        //Doesn't get the var, only if I remove it from master page model in source page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [How to read input value from the Request.Form collection by input name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723936/how-to-read-input-value-from-the-request-form-collection-by-input-name).

A control's Form key is the unique id of the control.  When you nest your control inside of a containing control (such as Content) that implements INamingContainer, ASP.NET will use the nesting control's name to qualify the nested control's id (and name).

So the Form key will be a concatenation of the Content and the TextBox control's IDs - something like "pageContent$txtTester".  You can look at the page's generated markup and use whatever the text box's id value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use response.redirect("yoursite.aspx?parameter1=value"); for that.

Comment: that's GET I want to use POST?

Comment: (If it were just one or two vars I would use GET, but I'm dealing with a lot at vars)